# Catch Errors in Protractor Runner

Tags: node.js, exception, protractor

Is there a way to catch specific errors thrown directly by `protractor`'s runner? For example, one uncaught exception is:

```
WARNING - pattern /var/www/smoran/repo/app/partials/app/app.controller.e2e.js did not match any files.
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

/var/www/smoran/repo/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Spec patterns did not match any files.
    at Runner.run (/var/www/smoran/repo/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:249:11)
    at TaskRunner.run (/var/www/smoran/repo/node_modules/protractor/lib/taskRunner.js:123:19)
    at createNextTaskRunner (/var/www/smoran/repo/node_modules/protractor/lib/launcher.js:220:20)
    at /var/www/smoran/repo/node_modules/protractor/lib/launcher.js:243:7
    at _fulfilled (/var/www/smoran/repo/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/var/www/smoran/repo/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/www/smoran/repo/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /var/www/smoran/repo/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:573:44
    at flush (/var/www/smoran/repo/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

This error is thrown when `protractor` can not find any files using the globbing pattern specified or, possibly, when none of the files it finds that do exist can be parsed by jasmine or mocha.

Now, I do not care about the situation that causes this error. I do not care whether protractor can or can not find files with my globbing patterns, and if I do care, I would like to throw my own error(s), as its errors are much too verbose, being in fact `uncaught exceptions`. Unfortunately, `protractor` is tripping me up at every turn where I try to do that. It seems to be throwing the error in the runner, then catching it in its dependency, `q`, then rethrowing it if it is being run under `NodeJS` (which it is).

I am using `gulp`, and I am using `child_process`'s `spawn` to spawn protractor, because all of `gulp`'s `protractor` plugins seem to be blacklisted or advised not to be used. My code would be too long to show here, but it essentially ends up like this:

```
gulp.task('protractor', function() {
  return spawn('protractor',
    [
      '--specs=' + notFoundTests
      otherArgs
    ],
    {
      stdio: 'inherit'
    });
});
```

I have protractor in my `PATH`, and `notFoundTests` is a string, not an array. I am using `stdio: 'inherit'` because I still want to see all the errors & output, but I am trying to find a way to filter it.

No matter what I try to catch, the error seems to not be emitted that way. It seems that it is not emitted as an error, so `spawn(...).on('error', function() {});` does not work. Using a `try catch` block around the call to `spawn` also does not work. Even using `process.on('uncaughtException');` does not catch it, even though it seems to be an uncaught exception.

My question is: How do I catch errors like this, that are thrown by `protractor` but not really returned? Does `protractor` provide any hooks, etc.? Also, why is it throwing this particular error? This seems to be an end-developer error, not something that `protractor` should handle itself.